# Can a character target multiple enemies with multiattack? Can they be separated?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, multiattack

The actual term "multiattack" only shows up in the PHB a few times, but it never indicates whether the subsequent attack is restricted to the same target as the first one. Because it is never explicitly stated I assume that multiattack can indeed target different opponents with each attack. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Following this logic brings me to the question of whether each of the multiattacks can be separated by movement. As in, a Brown Bear attacks a Wizard in range with his Bite attack, moves 30 feet to get beside a Fighter, and then attacks the Fighter with his Claw attack.

Is this how multiattack is meant to work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have the ability to make multiple attacks in a round, they can be against the same target or another target unless the specific ability prohibits it.

You can move between attacks, as mentioned on page 190 of the PHB.

> **Moving between Attacks**
>
> If you take an action that includes more than
>   one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by
>   moving between those attacks.